# How to install module 'ws' with 'Node.js'?

Tags: node.js, websocket, yocto, recipe

I would like to install module 'ws' with 'Node.js' in yocto morty system.
But I can't find recipe that Node.js includes 'ws' modules.

I tried following source, but Node.js cannnot find module 'ws'.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
        host : '0.0.0.0',
        port : 8080
});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
        ws.on('message', function(message) {
                console.log('received: %s', message);
                ws.send(message);
        });
});
```

The result is

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ws'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/root/app.js:1:85)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

So I can't install 'ws' with 'Node.js' recipe.
I am not familier with yocto so I don't know how I can install 'ws' with 'Node.js'.

I know install 'ws' by this command `npm install ws` in common OS.
Is it impossible to run in yocto environments like this command?

Answer (score -1):

You have to distinguish between runtime and compiletime when dealing with OpenEmbedded-based images, just like a Poky morty is. That means:

"**runtime**" is when you are actually running the image and using it. If it has internet connectivity, then you can have the npm utility installed and use it as known. This is done by adding "nodejs-npm" to your image, usually by utilizing either IMAGE_INSTALL if you already have a custom image recipe or CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL if its a one-off/first testing environment. (see http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_4.6.1.bb?h=morty#n80 to understand the inner workings, if interested.)

"**compiletime**" is when the image is created, before being installed onto actual hardware. This is one of the major strengths of the OpenEmbedded build system, but also one of the things that might be hard to understand. In the long project run, you usually want to completely automate image creation to include your application as well as all needed dependencies. In your case this means that you have to create a recipe for ws, a recipe for your application, and have your application recipe depend on the ws one then. Unfortunately this is still under development for npm modules, and morty is not exactly up to date. So if this is not a one-off tinkering project, you might

- find it useful to update to a newer release just to get more infrastructure (along with a way more recent NodeJS version)
- want learn about recipe writing and packaging. Here are some points to get you started: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-writing-a-new-recipe

My suggestion is to stick with the runtime solution for the first tests, and once you get the basic thing up and working, switch to compiletime as early as possible if you are heading for a real, reproductible product. Here, any delay in getting the infrastructure right as early as possible tends to backfire badly. If its only for your one experimentation board, you can probably stick with the runtime solution as long as it doesn what you want it to.

Comment: If anybody can shed some light on why this answer has been downvoted, please let me know so I can improve content/form for this or later answers. Thanks.